# Obtener PM en hora

Tags: c#, datetime

Estoy sacando la hora exacta `3:45` de la tarde (PM),desde mi maquina, en embargo, me sigue dando este resultado:
`11/3/2020 3:45:00 AM`, pero como se daran cuenta, el resultado da `AM`, no se porque razon si en mi computadora esta en `PM`, y requiero
el resultado en `PM` para una comparacion mas adelante.

De esta manera estoy realizando

```
var then= DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(3).AddMinutes(45);
```

Como puedo hacer que mi resultado sea `11/3/2020 3:45:00 PM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.Date` devuelve la fecha de hoy  a la media noche `12:00:00 AM`. Para que sean las 3 de la tarde hay que agregarle 15 horas.

```
var then= DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(45);
```